# How do I set AuthenticationScheme and AutomaticAuthenticate in .NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, .net-core

I tried to follow this guide to allow login of a user when running tests in .NET core 2

http://geeklearning.io/how-to-deal-with-identity-when-testing-an-asp-net-core-application/

It says I should configure authentication middleware for test purposes like this:

```
public class TestAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions  
{
    public virtual ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; } = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid", "test"),
        new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "test"),
        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", "test"),
        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn", "test"),
    }, "test");

    public TestAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        this.AuthenticationScheme = "TestAuthenticationMiddleware";
        this.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    }
}
```

This does not work since the AuthenticationOptions class have had the `AuthenticationScheme` and `AutomaticAuthenticate` properties removed from the AuthenticationOptions instance in .NET Core 2 cf.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#setting-default-authentication-schemes

So now I don't know how to get login in tests to work in .NET Core 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the config options in your startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(config => {
    this.AuthenticationScheme = "TestAuthenticationMiddleware";
    this.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
});
```

Most codes I find in .net core 2.0 use this way to configure the `AuthenticationOptions`. However if you need to create your own `AuthenticationOptions` class and use. You can make your own scheme which means you also need to make a `AuthenticationHandler<TestAuthenticationOptions>` class (lets call it `TestAuthenticationHandler`) and add it as a scheme.

```
services.AddAuthentication(config => {
    this.AuthenticationScheme = "TestAuthenticationMiddleware";
    this.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
})
.AddScheme<TestAuthenticationHandler, TestAuthenticationOptions>("TestAuthenticationMiddleware", o => {});
```

Comment: I get this error message:
AuthenticationOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AutomaticAuthenticate' and no extension method 'AutomaticAuthenticate' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationOptions' could be found

When I enter this code:

services.AddAuthentication(options => {
      options.AuthenticationScheme = "TestAuthenticationMiddleware";
      options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;

});

Comment: And this when I enter what you suggested:
'Startup' does not contain a definition for 'AuthenticationScheme' and no extension method 'AuthenticationScheme' accepting a first argument of type 'Startup' could be found

Comment: well it seems like once you set `AutomaticAuthenticate` to true, it is expecting some more set up. I am not entirely sure on how `AutomaticAuthenticate` works, I had just copied the values from your code. Did you try the first or second code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way anymore.
AuthenticationScheme can only be set in the Startup.cs. Branching like you did this is not possible any more.
Instead of test-Scheme, you should use the Scheme used in your application.

```
public class TestAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions  
{
public virtual ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; } = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
{
    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid", "test"),
    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "test"),
    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", "test"),
    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn", "test"),
}, "<ProductionScheme>");

    public TestAuthenticationOptions
    {
         //nothing to do here.
    }
}
```

In the Startup you have hopefully:

```
services.AddAuthentication("<ProductionScheme>");
```

Maybe this can help you:

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262